# Mean Value theorem to prove a function has at most one fixed point

Tags: calculus

A number $a$ is called a fixed point of a function $f$ if $f(a) = a$. Consider the function $f(x) = x^{87} + 4x + 2$, $x \in\mathbb{R}$.

(a) Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $f(x)$ cannot have more than one fixed point.

(b) Use the Intermediate Value Theorem and the result in (a) to show that $f(x)$ has exactly one fixed point.

Comment: Homework questions are frowned upon here without appropriate effort on your part. This is not a homework solving site. Please show effort. Also, don't ask more than question in a single post.

Answer (score 1):

(a) If $f$ has two distinc fixed points, namely $a<b$, then $$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. Then $f'(c)=1$. But $f'(x)=x^{86}+4\ge4$.

(b)Let $F(x)=f(x)-x$, which is continuous. $F(0)=2$ and $F(-1)=-2$. So there is $c\in (-1,0)$ such that $F(c)=0$ and, hence, $f(c)=c$. By (a), this is the only possible fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) - x$ is an increasing function.  It is positive at $x=0$ and negative at $x=-1$.